# How to set property defaults using the bulk uploader

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I've found that properties do not get created with default values in Model entities that are created via the bulk uploader. Any ideas why this is the case?

If I wanted to set a property value statically through the bulkloader.yaml file, can I?

```
class Message(db.Model):
  default = db.BooleanProperty(default=True)
  name    = db.StringProperty()
  message = db.StringProperty()
```

bulkloader.yaml: (I've tried this with and without specifying the transform for the boolean property.

```
transformers:
- kind: Message
  connector: csv
  connector_options:
   encoding: utf-8
   columns: from_header
  property_map:
   - property: default
     external_name: default
     import_transform: bool
   - property: name
     external_name: name
     import_transform: str
   - property: message
     external_name: message
     import_transform: unicode
```

Comment: Good question! I don't think this is possible with the current bulkloader using yaml configuration (other than by writing currently-undocumented postprocessing code). Could you not just add that column to your CSV?